# Javascript Objects format conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i convert this:

```
{key: "A", value: {count:2}}
{key: "B", value: {count:5}}
{key: "C", value: {count:1}}
```

INTO THIS:

```
{key:"A", value: 2}
{key:"B", value: 5}
{key:"C", value: 1}
```

Comment: You could use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015): `data.map(({ key, value: { count } }) => ({ key, count }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map`

```js
const data = [
  { key: "A", value: { count: 2 } },
  { key: "B", value: { count: 5 } },
  { key: "C", value: { count: 1 } },
]

const res = data.map((obj) => ({
  key: obj.key,
  value: obj.value.count,
}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map for this.

```js
let arr = [
  {key: "A", value: {count:2}},
  {key: "B", value: {count:5}},
  {key: "C", value: {count:1}}
];

let result = arr.map(obj => { return { key: obj.key, value: obj.value.count }});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or `for...of`

```js
const arr = [
  {key: "A", value: {count:2}},
  {key: "B", value: {count:5}},
  {key: "C", value: {count:1}}
];
for (let v of arr) v.value = v.value.count;
console.log(arr);
```

Though unlike `map()` this will mutate `arr`;